# Capturing Diagnostic request 27 01 / Seed using DiagGetParameterRaw on Capl/Canoe

Tags: security, seed, diagnostics, capl, canoe

I want to capture response of this request 27 01 but unfortunately I am getting 00 00...
I can see the request and the response on trace with positive response , thus I can see the seed on trace as well.

```
diagRequest ECU.SeedLevel1_Request req;
diagResponse ECU.SeedLevel1_Request resp;
//here code to enter extended session
..
..
..
// Send req to request seed 
DiagSendRequest(req);
DiagGetLastResponse(req,resp);
DiagGetParameterRaw(req, "Seed", gSeedArray, elcount(gSeedArray));
for(i=0;i<32;i++)
{
   write("%x",gSeedArray[i]);
}
gSeedArray always reports 00 ..
```

I tried for other requests for example reading dids and they works I captured the response and it s stored  , it doesn't work only for this security service.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the tracewindow, showing the request and response with all their parameters?

Comment: I am getting something like that , 67 01 + Seed is a 32 bytes

Comment: What is the return value of `diagGetParameterRaw`? Also, could you post a screenshot of the tracewindow, showing the request and response with all their parameters?